# Make asp:HyperLink the list items in an asp:DataList

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink, datalist

I have searched for a solution but something is missing and I don't know what it is. All of the code below works fine except `asp:HyperLink` gives me an error. I only need one

column with links for each Artist. The current code does fill a one column table. But I need each item to be a link.

Code:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataListArtists" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceArtists">
    <ItemTemplate>  
        <table class="table">  
            <tr>  
                <th colspan="2">  
                    <b>  
                    <%# Eval("Artist") %></b>  
                </th>  
            </tr>  
        </table>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Artist.aspx") %>'  Text='<%# Eval("Artist") %>' />
        </asp:HyperLink>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Error:

```
DataBinding: 'System.String' does not contain a property with the name 'aspx'.
    Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it   
    originated in the code.

    Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: DataBinding: 'System.String' does not contain a property with the name 'aspx'.

    Source Error:
    Line 82:                 </tr>  
    Line 83:             </table>
    Line 84:             <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Artist.aspx") %>'  Text='<%# Eval("Artist") %>' />
    Line 85:         </ItemTemplate>
```

Stack Trace:

```
   [HttpException (0x80004005): DataBinding: 'System.String' does not contain a property with the name 'aspx'.]
    System.Web.UI.DataBinder.GetPropertyValue(Object container, String propName) +8764405
    System.Web.UI.DataBinder.Eval(Object container, String[] expressionParts) +92
    System.Web.UI.DataBinder.Eval(Object container, String expression) +106
    System.Web.UI.TemplateControl.Eval(String expression) +40
    ASP.artists_aspx.__DataBinding__control7(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\lookerup\Desktop\mystuff\programming\apps\FlatbushMusic\FlatbushMusic\Artists.aspx:84
    System.Web.UI.Control.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e) +99
    System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding) +92
    System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind() +15
    System.Web.UI.Control.DataBindChildren() +211
    System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding) +102
    System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind() +15
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataList.CreateItem(Int32 itemIndex, ListItemType itemType, Boolean dataBind, Object dataItem) +125
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataList.CreateControlHierarchy(Boolean useDataSource) +459
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataList.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e) +54
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataList.DataBind() +55
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataList.EnsureDataBound() +60
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataList.CreateChildControls() +69
    System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() +87
    System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +44
    System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +171
    System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +171
    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +842
```

Comment: Is artist.aspx any result set in your dataset or a web page of your application ? If web page then do you really need to use Eval for this ?

Comment: Yes, artists,aspx lists artists and albums.aspx will list the artist and their albums. I'm not sure about Eval. I used an example I found.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way.

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Artist") + ".aspx" %>'  Text='<%# Eval("Artist") %>' />
```

Answer (score 0):

Thomson Mixab gave the answer in code. Which is:
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Artist") + ".aspx" %>'  Text='<%# Eval("Artist") %>' />